# Mongo JSInterpreter SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB 4.4.8, according to [mongo reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/), `$function` is new in 4.4, but running the following code, the server responded:

In my config file, `security.javascriptEnabled` is not set, so I think it should be default to `true`

> Command failed with error 139 (JSInterpreterFailure): 'SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'' on server {}. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'", "code": 139, "codeName": "JSInterpreterFailure"}

```js
    db.my_collection.aggregate(
    [
        {$addFields:{
            query: {
                $function:{
                    body: function(ss){
                        arr = ss.split('|');
                        result = {};
                        arr.forEach(element => {
                            kv = element.split(':');
                            result[kv[0]] = kv[1];
                        });
                        return result['q']},
                    args: ['my_field'],
                    lang:'js'
                }
            }
            }}
    ]);
```

The function can be executed successfully on my computer, but mongo seemed not be able to parse the keyword `function`, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I tried in the mongo shell directly and it worked, might be a problem with DataGrip rather than with mongo surprisingly. As to why? I don't know.

So try the same aggregation in the console instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33326407)